# Google Sheets: Absolute Reference in Formula when Adding Column

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that I want to calculate the average of the first three values in a row...

For example:

```
          Column A     Column B     Column C     Column D
Row 1      7/1/2017     6/1/2017     5/1/2017   
Row 2      $934         $392         $214
```

So my formula is

```
=average($A$2:$C$2)
```

This works fine, until I add a new column to the left of Column A to add the newest month's data which now looks like this:

```
          Column A     Column B     Column C     Column D
Row 1                  7/1/2017     6/1/2017     5/1/2017   
Row 2                  $934         $392         $214
```

The issue is that spreadsheet automatically changes the formula to

```
=average($B$2:$D$2)
```

when what I really want is to retain the original formula so it will continue to give the the average of the most recent three months of data.

Here is a link to a spreadsheet so you can see what is happening, sheet one is before added column, and sheet two is after adding column.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XE2zyFGCHUfSf44vNHwXij59I68LJEL_L7cNSf0-uag/edit?usp=sharing

How can I do this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a sensible place to put such a formula is in ColumnA (having made room for it!) hence:

```
=average(OFFSET(A2,,1,1,3))
```

Comment: Offset is a good answer.  I tested it and it works very well for my needs.  Thanks.  I'll see if anyone has any more answers before marking as solved, though, since there might be some other interesting options.